# my tooltip hide and not working on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

please, help... i did this(i'm totally new in jquery and javascript ), but my tooltip hide and not working on mouseout, and i need users interact with it, i need(hard) to show content(and a link to an iframe or something like that) from an area that it's in inside a map(country with states) area that i create by myself, here it's my code:

```
 (function($){ $('.tooltip').hide('show');

    $('div.area-tip').mouseover(function(e){
       tip = $(this).attr('id');
tip = tip.substring(tip.indexOf('-')+1);
       cursorX = e.pageX;
       cursorY = e.pageY;

       $('div[id='+tip+']').css('top',cursorY);
       $('div[id='+tip+']').css('left',cursorX);
       //$('div[id='+tip+']').show('delay: 400');
      // $('div[id='+tip+']').hide('fixed');

    });
    $('tooltip').mouseout(function(){
          find('div-area-tip').stop(true,false).animate({opacity:'show', left:'-100px'}, 30);
    });

    })(jQuery);
```

/***************************************\

```
<body>
<p>mi mapa </p>
<div id="map_cub">
  <img src="images/Map_de_cuba-v2.png" alt="Cuba" width="700" height="284" usemap="#Map">
      <map name="Map">
<div id="area-1" class="area-tip"><area shape="poly" coords="125,50,143,82,35,116,84,67" href="#" target="_self" alt="Pinar del Rio">
<div class="tooltip" id="1">
  <p class="p">pinar</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat.</p>
</div>
</div>
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" id="area-2" coords="130,44,130,45,128,46,147,75,185,64,174,40" href="#" target="_self" alt="Artemisa">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="195,30,176,39,187,48,203,35" href="#" alt="La Habana">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="205,33,201,42,187,50,187,64,223,71,226,58,222,43,223,36" href="#" target="_self" alt="Mayabeque">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="231,36,229,62,225,74,195,82,217,96,244,103,261,103,267,80,286,68,273,42,252,35" href="#" target="_self" alt="Matanzas">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="289,46,287,56,291,72,309,75,316,93,322,109,333,99,356,85,329,57" href="#" target="_self" alt="Villa Clara">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="291,74,283,80,273,80,271,97,289,101,299,109,313,118,319,111,309,79" href="#" target="_self" alt="Cienfuegos">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="380,87,360,87,353,95,341,100,335,105,320,115,316,123,345,134,357,136,374,138,372,109" href="#" target="_self" alt="Sancti Spiritus">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="393,87,383,87,378,103,382,113,379,128,389,135,401,139,420,123,423,112,433,107" href="#" target="_self" alt="Ciego de Avila">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="433,108,430,120,428,125,419,130,410,135,402,141,408,160,410,173,433,190,448,193,466,174,479,172,490,157,490,143" href="#" target="_self" alt="Camaguey">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="498,148,493,159,488,168,478,174,466,177,457,189,464,192,478,191,486,187,506,187,512,187,520,173,534,163" href="#" target="_self" alt="Las Tunas">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="486,189,488,201,494,210,490,218,469,229,463,237,456,248,474,247,491,242,505,235,518,235,533,231,544,218,546,207,524,193" href="#" target="_self" alt="Granma">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="543,160,536,168,530,172,524,175,518,186,546,202,560,201,591,199,610,202,630,207,631,196,583,189,573,180,582,180,583,170,570,165" href="#" target="_self" alt="Holguin">
        <area shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="554,206,547,218,545,225,539,231,531,235,528,240,542,239,556,239,571,238,583,242,592,244,590,235,594,224,593,213,593,204" href="#" target="_self" alt="Santiago de Cuba">
 <div id="area-2" class="area-tip"><area shape="poly" coords="634,200,630,206,623,207,615,206,607,204,596,204,594,213,594,225,593,232,597,236,604,237,615,232,621,236,631,228,661,227,665,214,650,212" target="_self" alt="Guantanamo"/>
<div class="tooltip" id="2">
  <p>guantanamo</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>
</div>
 <area id="area-15" shape="poly" class="area-tip" coords="152,110,140,121,145,135,152,144,172,135,165,117" href="#" target="_self" alt="Isla de la Juventud">

  </map>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.area-tip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**************************************/

Comment: Can you provide a snippet/fiddle as a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Also, in what way does it 'not work'?  Does the tooltip animation not run, so it's always shown?

Comment: not enough info, sorry, can you post html code?

Comment: hi, thanks for hel... here it's my html...

Answer (score 0):

You need a period in your tooltip jQuery selector when you call mouseout. Also,  find('div-area-tip') should be $('div.area-tip').